# How to show with the following conditions that the language L isn't context-free?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, regular-language

If we have a language

[image: language K]

Now I have to use the language K  which isn't context-free and the lemma that the intersection of a context-free language with a regular language is context-free to show that the language [image]

is not context free.

Hope somebody can help

Comment: I don't know how to clasificate this question. I guess this is not for stackoverflow. I can't be brave to vote this question as offtopic, but I think that's at least **unclear what you are asking**. What do you need?

Comment: How to proove that L isnt context free? Normally I'll proove this with the pumping lemma but in this case my prof asked for this special method of prooving that L isnt context free. (Also don't know where to ask this question)

Comment: I wish someone can help you. It's not me. I don't know what is that language / lemma or how it's related with computer development. Sorry :(

Comment: I defined the languages (or you can say grammars) K and L, and its a theorem that says that the intersection of those languages(grammars) are context-free. Now I only have to proof with this theorem. As you can see on my profile I asked a similar question to regular grammar and it got answered also on StackOverflow are many questions to regular/context-free/context-sensitive languages and to proofs for them, so I think this is a legit question.

Comment: Yeah, no doubt about legitime question. Simply I don't know nothing about this topic. I wish someone can help you , but it's not me. Sorry again and good luck.

Comment: You could try at the computing science site, http://cs.stackexchange.com, but they also like you to show that you've tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

L intersected with a+b+a+b+ is K. Since you know that K is not cf, by the Lemma, L cannot be cf either.